# How to access ApplicationContext in Spring Boot main method?

Tags: spring-boot

I am just learning Spring Boot. I am creating standalone Spring Boot applications. I want to retrieve beans using applicationContext.getBean("myGreetService"). I’m doing this for learning purposes only. This is not for real-time project.

I want to retrieve the ApplicationContext in the main() method of Spring Boot application. What codes are available to get the applicationContext in the main() method?

This is what I have so far and I need codes for filling in the blanks.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoBootApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(DemoBootApplication.class, args);

      // how can I access the application context here?
      // i want to do:  GreetService myService = applicationContext.getBean("myGreetService");

   }

}
```

I am using Spring Boot 2.6 and IntelliJ 2021.2.3.

Answer (score 4):

`SpringApplication#run` returns application context, so you can do:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoBootApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(DemoBootApplication.class, args);

      ctx.getBean("myGreetService");
   }
}
```

But this is not an idiomatic way to do things in Spring. If you just want to run some piece of code after application startup, use `ApplicationRunner`:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoBootApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(DemoBootApplication.class, args);
   }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner applicationRunner(MyService myService) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println(myService);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding on the top of this answer: the @Bean method that returns ApplicationRunner can take an ApplicationContext argument so you can access all beans from the context: `var bean = (MyBeanClass) applicationContext.getBean("myBeanClass");`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to inject the **ApplicationContext**

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;
```

On any bean/component of your spring boot application, including the **entrypoint** class itself.

Check this:

- https://zetcode.com/springboot/applicationcontext/